# Product of $f(x)\cdot f(x)$ when the domain is empty

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, products, elementary-functions

Is this in some way a meaningful mathematical expression ? Would the product be equal to just $f(x)$ on its own ?

Comment: A function with empty domain is just the empty set.

Comment: The function has no arguments so expressions like $f(x)\cdot f(x)$ do not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that "$\cdot$" is a function restricted to some domain, let's call it $D$. So, for every $a,b \in D$ we can evaluate the function $\cdot$ at these values and in return get a value $\cdot(a,b)$ which we also denote with $a \cdot b$.

Now let $f$ be a function with empty domain. Then $f = \emptyset$ and thus there are no $x,y$ with $(x,y) \in f$ or in other words, there are no $x,y$ such that $f(x) = y$. In order to evaluate $\cdot(f(x),f(x))$, however, we need some $y$ such that $f(x) = y$. In fact $\cdot(f(x),f(x)) = \cdot(y,y) = y \cdot y$ for precisely some such (and hence unique) $y$.

To summarize this argument: If $f$ doesn't take values, we can't use these values as parameters in other functions. So, no, $f(x) \cdot f(x)$ doesn't make sense for the empty function $f$. In fact, $f(x)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Then again, the only function $f\colon \emptyset\to \Bbb R$ has the property $f(x)=f(x)\cdot f(x)$ for all $x$ in its domain.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That depends on how you formalize it. If it's $\forall x \in \mathrm{dom}(f) : ( \ldots )$, sure. But you could also formalize it as $\exists x \in \mathrm{dom}(f) : ( \ldots) \wedge \forall y \in \mathrm{dom}(f) : (\ldots)$.